# Cancel button not behaving correctly with jQuery load event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a cancel button that is not working correctly.

When I hit it, it cancels, but then reloads the page.

I thought adding **"preventDefault"** would fix, but it did not.

Here is some background:

On my page called playerData.aspx, it displays the character stats in the this element:

`<div id="mainGameText">`.

That data is loaded via this page "**characterGeneratorDisplay.aspx**"

I have a block of jQuery code in "**playerData.aspx**" that controls the character display/edit area that is supposed to do the following:

> - When the page loads, it displays the character data.
> - When the user clicks this area(), the editor loads.

Here is that block of jQuery:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //initial load character read-only
        $("#mainGameText").load("../character/characterGeneratorDisplay.aspx?charID=<%= Session("currentCharID") %>");

        //load character editor on div click
        $("#mainGameText").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#ajaxNodeText").load('../character/characterGeneratorEdit.aspx?charID=<%= Session("currentCharID") %>');
        });
        return false;
    });

</script>
```

The above script is working.  It loads the needed data and it loads the editor when that area is clicked.

In the **characterGeneratorEdit.aspx** page, I have a "**Save**" and "**Cancel**" button.

The "**Save**" button is a .NET control because it does some backend .NET and database stuff when saving the character.

And the closeWindow() function reloads the read-only page:

function closeEditor() {

```
        $("#mainGameText").load("../character/characterGeneratorDisplay.aspx?charID=<%= Session("currentCharID") %>");
```

}

The problem is, when I hit cancel, it does load "**characterGeneratorDisplay.aspx**", but then it re-loads the character editor(***characterGeneratorEdit.aspx***) again.

I thought adding "**e.preventDefault()**" would fix that, but it hasn't.

How can I get the cancel button to just close "**characterGeneratorEdit.aspx**" and reload "**characterGeneratorDisplay.aspx**" in the  element?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try [event.stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

Also, ensure that your "Cancel" button does not have "submit" type or return false in your onClick handler.

Comment: I tried putting e.stopPropagation(); first in my closeEditor() function but that didn't work.  Then I tried putting it in place of e.preventDefault() in the onclick event, and that didn't work.